# Executing script for add primary keys to all tables returns error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, ddl

I want to add Primary Key `IDD` to every `'Temp...'` table in the schema. I'm trying to do it the following way:

```
DECLARE @addId VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @addId = @addId + 'ALTER TABLE ['+ TABLE_NAME +'] ADD IDD int IDENTITY(1,1);ALTER TABLE ['+TABLE_NAME +'] ADD PRIMARY KEY (IDD);' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Temp%'
EXEC (@addId );
```

I'm returned with such error:

`Multiple identity columns specified for table 'TempTable'. Only one identity column per table is allowed.`

What is my wrongdoing?

EDIT: There is no Primary Key already defined in the tables.

Comment: well... the message says, there is already an identity column defined in your table. did you check the table definition?

Comment: There is no Primary Key defined in the Table before running this query.

Comment: Ok, there is. Jesus sorry.

Comment: Could you provide the schema of the table TempTable?

Comment: Took you 4 minutes to figure out that your script was wrong. Newsflash - any error you encounter is highly likely to be caused by your own code. Also stop assuming. The error message said NOTHING about a primary key - it mentioned multiple identity columns.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT @addId = @addId + 
ALTER TABLE ['+ TABLE_NAME +'] ADD IDD int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1);
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Temp%'
```

Comment: This will try to alter the table named `'+ TABLE_NAME +'`. In any case the error is clear. There's nothing wrong with the OP's statement. The table already has a key.

Comment: yes, i think you right , but i hope it'll allow write more briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Use  this query to get all table which doesn't have primary key:

```
select * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME NOT IN(SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE  CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PRIMARY KEY')
```

And modify your dynamic query accordingly.